# Assign tasks to members in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm not familiar with SVN and uses it first time with Android Studio, I have worked with Microsoft's TFS before, 
and want to know is there i SVN option "Assign Task" like in TFS, for members know what they have to do?

Comment: Check this out for Task management https://www.assembla.com/home

Comment: TFS includes source code control and task management. SVN only deals with source code control. You will need to find another product specifically focused on task management.